# WPF Trigger, is it like an if/else?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, triggers

I've been reading into Triggers lately and am trying to incorporate it into my application but I keep getting the thought that the triggers act like if statements, if this property has a value of this, do this to the control.

What I'm wondering is if we can change a different controls' properties in another trigger? I'm looking to either remove an extra row that is created dynamically or increase the width of a button by a columnspan of 3 only if a button is hidden or specific label text is on the window.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, but anything I'm trying is requiring me to only change the property of the control that is within the trigger, it won't allow me to change a property of a control outside of the one in the trigger.

Here's what I'm wanting to do:

```
<Style x:Key="Triggers" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Label.Content" Value="Test Label1: ">
                <Setter TargetName="Button1" Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3" /> 'Error 13  Cannot find the Trigger target 'Button1'.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)    

            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>   
    </Style>
```

What my mind is coming up with is the trigger is the IF, the setter is the code within the IF if the logic matches(property is true) - so If the Label contains the text 'Test Label1: " then increase button width by 3 columns.  Am I thinking triggers have the functionality they don't and is this possible to do within xaml?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is like.

Comment: You should put the condition logic in the ViewModel and then use `DataTrigger` in the Style targeting the button to change its property accordingly. Anyway you have to use the `Trigger` of the Button's style, not the Trigger of the Label's Style.

Answer (score 0):

A `Trigger` is somewhat like an `if` condition in XAML. However, when using a `Trigger` to change a property dependant on another control, try to remember this rule of thumb:

> Add the `Trigger` to the control that must do something in reaction to a change in another control

In your case, you want the `Button` to span some columns when the `Label.Content` = `Test Label1:`, so you'd need to apply the `Trigger` to the `Button` instead. Furthermore, to read the value of the `Label.Content` from the `Button`, you'll need to use a `DataTrigger`. Try this:

```
<Button Content="Something">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=LabelName}" 
                    Value="Test Label1: ">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="3" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```